# Problem with the Fourier transform of a function

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I'm having some troubles with this one:

$$\mathcal F(e^{-|x|} +|x|e^{-|x|})$$

I know that $\displaystyle\mathcal F(e^{-|x|})={1\over \pi (1+w^2)}$ but the second part is where I get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can write that part as

$$2 \Re{\left [ \int_0^{\infty} dx \, x \, e^{-(1-i w)x}\right ]} = 2 \Re{\left [ \frac1{(1-i w)^2}\right]} = 2\frac{1-w^2}{(1+w^2)^2 }$$

Comment: Much more elegant than my solution=)

Answer (score 0):

If we know how to use Fourier transform in the sense of distributions:

$$F[|x|e^{-|x|}] = F[|x|]\ast F[e^{-|x|}] = \frac{1}{\xi^2}\ast \frac{1}{1+\xi^2} = -\frac{\xi^2-1}{(1+\xi^2)^2}.$$
This is true up to constant factor that depends on your Fourier transform conventions (wolframalpha says that this constant should be $-\sqrt{2/\pi}$).